# Send 50KB array from C++ to Python (NumPy) on Windows

Tags: python, c++, numpy, ipc

I have a C++ and a Python application on Windows (7+). I wish to send a ~50KB array of binary data (int[], float[], or double[]) from the C++ application to a NumPy array in the Python application in real time. I want <100ms latency, but can handle up to 500ms. I'm unsure of the correct way to do this.

I believe NumPy technically stores its arrays as just an array of binary data just like C++ (assuming a reasonable C++ compiler, like modern MSVC or GCC). Therefore technically it should be very easy, but I haven't been able to identify a good way to do this.

My current plan would be to use a memory mapped file, and then handle locking the memory-mapped file with more traditional IPC such as the Win32 message pump or a semaphore.

I'm however not sure whether NumPy can read straight from a memory mapped file. It can create a memory-map to a file on disk with numpy.memmap, but this doesn't seem to work for pure memory mapped file where I just have a name or a handle.

I don't know if this is the right approach. Maybe I can get it to work, but ideally I would also want to do it the right way and not be surprised by nasty consequences of me coding stuff I don't understand.

I would appreciate any help or pointers to material that might help me figure out the correct way to do this.

UPDATE:
My C++ code (proof-of-concept) would look like this:

```
// Host application.
// Creates 20 byte memory mapped file with name "Global\test_mmap_file" and
// containing 5 uint32s.
// Note: Requires SeCreateGlobalPrivilege to create global memory mapped 
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
file
int main()
{
    HANDLE file_mapping_handle = NULL;
    unsigned int* buffer = 0;

    assert(sizeof(unsigned int) == 4); // Require compatability with np.uint32

    const size_t buffer_sz = 5 * sizeof(unsigned int);

    file_mapping_handle = CreateFileMapping(
        INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
        NULL,
        PAGE_READWRITE,
        0,
        buffer_sz,
        L"Global\\test_mmap_file");

    if (!file_mapping_handle)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateFileMapping failed (Host).\n";
        std::cout << "Error code: 0x" << std::hex << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        return 1;
    }

    buffer = (unsigned int*)MapViewOfFile(
        file_mapping_handle,
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
        0,
        0,
        buffer_sz);

    if (!buffer)
    {
        CloseHandle(file_mapping_handle);
        std::cout << " MapViewOfFile failed (Host).\n";
        std::cout << "Error code: 0x" << std::hex << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        return 1;
    }

    buffer[0] = 2;
    buffer[1] = 3;
    buffer[2] = 5;
    buffer[3] = 7;
    buffer[4] = 11;
    std::cout << "Data sent, press enter to exit.\n";

    std::cin.get();

    UnmapViewOfFile(buffer);
    CloseHandle(file_mapping_handle);

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted some way to access this shared memory from Python and create a numpy array. I tried,

```
import numpy as np
L_mm = np.memmap('Global\\test_mmap_file')
```

but this fails as Global\test_mmap_file is not a filename. Following the hints given by abarnert I constructed the following client program which seems to work:

```
import numpy as np
import mmap

mm = mmap.mmap(0,20,'Global\\test_mmap_file')
L = np.frombuffer(mm,dtype = np.uint32)
print (L)
mm.close()
```

This requires admin privileges for both programs to run (or giving the user the right to SeCreateGlobalObjects). However I think this should easily be bypassed by not giving the shared memory a global name, and instead duplicating the handle and passing it to the Python program. It also doesn't control access to the shared memory properly, but that should be easy with a semaphore or some other such construct.

Comment: What does "this doesn't seem to work" mean? It definitely can read straight from a memory-mapped file, using either `memmap` or `load` with `mmap_mode`, or just `mmap`ping the file manually and using it as a `buffer` for the `ndarray` constructor as the `memmap` docs explain. [Here's an example of it working](http://pastebin.com/pqs9UB7K). So, if it's not working for you, you need to give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain what you expected and what you got instead.

Comment: You can use the Numpy C-API to create a numpy array over a previously allocated memory segment, probably using [`PyArray_SimpleFromData`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData). OpenCV does something like that, and can generate images with about x1000 times more data than you want at 60 fps, so below 16ms latency. Using the hard drive for this seems like a complete waste here. But it is hard to tell if you don't show some code of what your C++ and Python would look like...

Comment: "This doesn't seem to work" means that I couldn't find a way to access shared memory without an underlying file. I looked into the mmap module you mentioned and that seems to solve it. I will edit the main post with my updated proof-of-concept code and what I tried.